# Top n splits of leaf nodes from decision tree

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I'm using `rpart` pacakge of `R` and I want to extract the top 3 splits for the leaf node instead of just the best. Is it possible to do this without changing the source code of `rpart` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the splits like this:

```
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)
fit$splits
```